# Как отделяются друг от друга два придаточных подряд?

Tags: пунктуация

А значит, всегда будет жить надежда на наше достойное будущее, о котором мечтали наши ветераны и за которое не будет стыдно живущим.

Answer (score 2):

Между однородными придаточными предложениями, соединенными неповторяющимся соединительным или разделительным союзом, запятая не ставится, ([Розенталь](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect109), § 109, п.3)

**А значит, всегда будет жить надежда на наше достойное будущее, о котором мечтали наши ветераны и за которое не будет стыдно живущим.**